# Replace code for single quote is not working

Tags: javascript, html

Replace code is not working for single quote so please help me.
Some place it is working and some place it will not work.

Javascript Code:

```
var demo = "Broadcasted on Zee TV from Monday to Friday, the Indian television soap opera Kumkum Bhagya has long been revolving around the mystery of Tanu’s pregnancy. Tanu, a cunning, sly and guileful character in the Kumkum Bhagya serial has been fooling Abhi, the rock star. She is actually pregnant with Nikhil, her ex-boyfriend, but claims to be the mother of Abhi’s child. Except Abhi, almost everyone in the show knows who Tanu is pregnant with. But, the mystery will remain unrevealed until Abhi knows the reality of Tanu’s pregnancy. The coming episodes of Kumkum Bhagya, Pragya's DNA disclosure is likely to reveal the secret.";
var demo1 = demo.replace(/[']/g,";");
//alert(demo1);
document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = demo1;
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="hello">
</div>
```

Please use this as reference:
https://jsfiddle.net/h3sujuLx/

Comment: You don't use the same character in your sample text and in the replace function. Both of them is an apostrophe, both they have different chracter codes, so the function does not find a match.

Comment: But dear, I want to handle both in the same document because when I fetch that string in java using request.getParameter method then, apostrophe is disappear from string.
So, tell me how to handle that problem?

Comment: I think @Duncan's solution will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your string you have the unicode character 'right single quotation mark' and also an apostrophe, but in your regular expression you have an apostrophe which is a different character. If you want to replace both characters you need to include both in your regular expression:

```
var demo1 = demo.replace(/['’]/g,";");
```

Specifically compare: `Tanu’s` (right single quotation mark) and `Pragya's` (apostrophe)

To make this easy to type you can use the unicode escape sequence instead of the character:

```
var demo1 = demo.replace(/['\u2019]/g,";");
```

Comment: Look carefully at the string, the two characters look similar but they aren't identical. I added two of the words into my answer cut and pasted from your question so you can compare more easily..

Comment: When I write this new above replace code in jsp page and when I inspect in source for that the, I get replace(/â€™/g,"&apos;") instead of replace(/['’]/g,"&apos;")

Comment: @SaurabhAren it sounds like you are having issues getting the unicode character into your source code. To avoid problems just use the escape sequence \u2019 (see edit)

Comment: I want to replace both quotation mark and apostrophe with standard single inverted comma. Have you any solution related with that.

Comment: Thanx Duncan, your effort is the precious for me.